# Bower not found when Running JHipster

Tags: npm, bower, jhipster

I had some issue recently and the problem seems to be very badlty documented so I make here a post to explain it and the solution as well.

When running JHipster and do all the installation step, you may have some issue running the ./gradlew bootRun (bootRun is not necessary as it is the task by default).

If you have the following problem :

[image: Problem you got]

You CAN'T solve it with sudo. I don't really now why, but the console will logged you that you don't need sudo to run that (really frustrating).

You can find the solution in the comment (It seems that I have to separate the question from the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is that the file you can't run has the wrong username or group name and can't be ran due to that.

So you have to change it by the command :

```
chown -R
```

The syntax is :

```
chown -R Username:groupName path/of/your/file
```

But then the question is : How to know what to write in username and groupName ?

You have to go to your directory (where you run ./gradlew ) and type :

```
ls -l
```

It will show you all the files in the directory, with the username and group name associated.

The username is in **column 3** and group name in ** column 4** .

Normally, this should be **all the same here**. But that's quite normal : The problematic file is not here. But you have here the name your problematic file should have.

Just run the command and this should work !